# log4j showing error when it's picking up my configuration

Tags: java, log4j

I'm having the same issue described here: [Log4j Warning while initializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685510/log4j-warning-while-initializing)

My application has a `log4j.properties` that allows me to configure `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout` correctly.  However I still see:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

When running the application.

My log4j.properties currently reads:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c:%L - %m%n

#log4j.category.org.springframework=DEBUG,stdout
```

I've also tried adding the properties file to my config via:

```
@PropertySource(value= {
        "classpath:/log4j.properties",
        "classpath:/application.properties"
})
```

How can I make this error go away?  I can toggle between `DEBUG` and `INFO` just fine via this file, so I know it's being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this error go away by adding the line

```
log4j.logger.org.jboss.logging=INFO, stdout
```

to your log4j.properties.
I don't know why, but it seems like something sets the additivity of `org.jboss.logging` to `false`, causing it to ignore the root appender(s). So you can either find that magical spot or you add the the line above.

Comment: Looks like `log4j.category` is deprecated and we should use `log4j.logger` instead.